# cannot delete root node in a binary search tree

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**deleting the root(the first node i enter strong text) node shows the error 'TreeNode' object has no attribute 'findSuccessor'
when i try to delete the first node that is inserted it shows an attribute eroor
but the nodes that are inserted later get delete
can you tell me what is wrong with code **

```
class TreeNode:
    
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self

    def isRightChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.rightChild == self

    def isRoot(self):
        return not self.parent

    def isLeaf(self):
        return not (self.rightChild or self.leftChild)

    def hasAnyChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild or self.leftChild

    def hasBothChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild and self.leftChild

    def replaceNodeData(self,key,value,lc,rc):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = value
        self.leftChild = lc
        self.rightChild = rc
        if self.hasLeftChild():
            self.leftChild.parent = self
        if self.hasRightChild():
            self.rightChild.parent = self


class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def put(self,key,val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key,val,self.root)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(key,val)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                   self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                   currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                   self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                   currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)

    def __setitem__(self,k,v):
        self.put(k,v)

    def get(self,key):
        if self.root:
            res = self._get(key,self.root)
            if res:
                
                return res.payload
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def _get(self,key,currentNode):
        
        if not currentNode:
            return None
        elif currentNode.key == key:
            return currentNode
        elif key < currentNode.key:
            return self._get(key,currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            return self._get(key,currentNode.rightChild)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __contains__(self,key):
        if self._get(key,self.root):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def delete(self,key):
        
        if self.size > 1:
            
            nodeToRemove = self._get(key,self.root)
            if nodeToRemove:
                self.remove(nodeToRemove)
                self.size = self.size-1
            else:
                raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')
        elif self.size == 1 and self.root.key == key:
            self.root = None
            self.size = self.size - 1
        else:
            raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')

    def __delitem__(self,key):
        
        self.delete(key)

    def spliceOut(self):
        if self.isLeaf():
            if self.isLeftChild():
                
                self.parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                self.parent.rightChild = None
        elif self.hasAnyChildren():
            if self.hasLeftChild():
                
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    
                    self.parent.leftChild = self.leftChild
                else:
                    
                    self.parent.rightChild = self.leftChild
                    self.leftChild.parent = self.parent
        else:
                    
            if self.isLeftChild():
                        
                self.parent.leftChild = self.rightChild
            else:
                self.parent.rightChild = self.rightChild
                self.rightChild.parent = self.parent

    def findSuccessor(self):
        
        succ = None
        if self.hasRightChild():
            succ = self.rightChild.findMin()
        else:
            if self.parent:
                
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    
                    succ = self.parent
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = None
                    succ = self.parent.findSuccessor()
                    self.parent.rightChild = self
        return succ

    def findMin(self):
        
        current = self
        while current.hasLeftChild():
            current = current.leftChild
        return current

    def remove(self,currentNode):
        
        if currentNode.isLeaf(): #leaf
            if currentNode == currentNode.parent.leftChild:
                currentNode.parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                currentNode.parent.rightChild = None
        elif currentNode.hasBothChildren(): #interior
            
            succ = currentNode.findSuccessor()
            succ.spliceOut()
            currentNode.key = succ.key
            currentNode.payload = succ.payload

        else: # this node has one child
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild
                else:
                
                    currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.leftChild.key,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.payload,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.leftChild,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.rightChild)
            else:
                
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.rightChild
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
                else:
                    currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.rightChild.key,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.payload,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.leftChild,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.rightChild)
```